# Formato errado na conversão de String para Date

Tags: java

Eu tenho a seguinte data em formato de `String`: *12-12-2017*

Estou tentando passar este valor para `java.util.Date`. Estou tentando assim:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            final String valor = cell.getStringCellValue();
            return formatter.parse(valor);
```

O problema é que meu retorno está assim:

```
Tue Dec 12 00:00:00 BRST 2017
```

Quero que retorne exatamente como está na String, alguém sabe como posso resolver ?

Comment: Este é o formato do tipo Date. Não há como retornar da forma como você quer neste tipo, a não ser que retorne como string.

Comment: Ahhh, sério ? Mas eu vou conseguir contornar porque como isso vai ser exibido em uma tela(jsf), eu uso um converter.

Comment: Obrigado @Articuno